# Подсчет количества подключенных продуктов

Tags: sql

Есть таблица: client_id, date_start, date_end, name_product

Мне нужно посчитать количество продуктов  клиентов на каждую из дат, когда подключен продукт (date-start - дата подключения, date-end - дата отключения:

```
client-id | start-date | end-date   | Amount-products 
123       | 2004-12-07 | 2005-12-06 | 1
123       | 2005-01-19 | 2005-11-19 | 2
123       | 2005-12-07 | 2006-06-06 | 1
```

Comment: 1) Укажите точно СУБД, включая версию. 2) Создайте fiddle. Или хотя бы добавьте CREATE TABLE источника и INSERT INTO данных, которые дают показанный результат. 3) Если есть запись об одном и том же продукте для одного и того же клиента с перекрывающимися диапазонами - в диапазоне пересечения данный продукт считается как один или как два? и не надо говорить "таких записей нет" - либо покажите структурой таблицы, что внесение таких записей невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
  client-id,
  start-date,
  end-date,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      products
    WHERE
      (
        date_start > start-date
        OR date_start = start-date
      )
      AND (
        date_end < end-date
        OR date_end = end-date
      )
  )
FROM
  clients
```

Это только в том случае, если я правильно понял задачу.